# CSS transitions in Edge and IE11 not working

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I don't often find myself with CSS issues, but this has me scratching my head.

In this plunk http://plnkr.co/i2Fxol, everything works exactly as expected in all browsers, with the exception of IE10 and 11 and Edge completely failing to apply css transitions to *some* elements, not all. And no matter how much I look at it, I cannot see why it's failing in those particular places. (CSS added here but it needs to be seen in context as this is a really simplistic view)

```
#navigation ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

Essentially, they burp when the accordion is open and the menus are available to expand and contract in the 0.2 seconds stated. All the other transitions work.

*Oh, and there is now way that I am ever going to add  closures to svg paths within HTML5 just to remove those utterly pointless warnings in IE and Edge.*

### edit

The initial heights for the accordions are gathered on load with this:

```
...
var initialHeights = document.getElementsByClassName("level-1");
var values = [];
for(var i = 0; initialHeights.length > i; i++){
  values.push(initialHeights[i].offsetHeight);
}
...
```

They are then zeroed inline with the values stored safely in an array using:

```
function toZero(){
  for(i = 0; mainSubMenus.length > i; i++){
    mainSubMenus[i].setAttribute("style", "height:0;");
  }
}
toZero();
```

This allows the use of css to transition between a zero height and a known value.

#### brainfart

I thought that maybe the following would cure the ill:

```
mainSubMenus[i].style.height = 0;
```

I was wrong.

Comment: Are you animating any element from `display: none` to `display: block`?

Comment: Nope, height. The height is fetched from load when the height of the elements is known before they are set to 0.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which animation isn't working properly? A GIF contrasting the behavior of Edge vs Chrome would be helpful too; you can get a great app for this over at http://screentogif.codeplex.com/.

Comment: [Edge is this one](http://adobe.ly/2a2iwG2), and [Chrome is this one](http://adobe.ly/2aeImHQ). You will see in the Edge one that the accordion transitions to expand and collapse are instantaneous, whereas those in Chrome (and all others except IE) are fluid. Those are the _only_ animations that don't play as expected. All others work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue here is with the lack of an initial height. If you cycle over the elements, and set their heights equal to that of their computed height style, you could then use your *collapse* style to override the height to 0px, triggering a transition between two explicit numbers.

```js
var box = document.querySelector( ".box" );

// Set the box's initial height to its computed height
box.style.height = window.getComputedStyle( box ).height;

// Hide the box
box.classList.add( "collapsed" );

// Click will toggle a "collapsed" class on the box
document.addEventListener( "click", e => box.classList.toggle( "collapsed" ) )
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.collapsed {
  height: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="box">
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. The heights are known at page load and held in memory. They are then injected into the style attribute on click 

`var initialHeights = document.getElementsByClassName("level-1");
var values = [];
for(var i = 0; initialHeights.length > i; i++){
  values.push(initialHeights[i].offsetHeight);
}`. I also need the expanded class applied and removed at the same time as collapsed is removed and added. I did use toggle(), but opted for a more verbose and accurate method of element.classList.add() and element.classList(remove). I'll give your method a shot and get back.

Comment: I tried that and it sort of worked until I added a sub-accordion to the fray and it all fell apart with the heights not being honoured, so I went back to the original version of populating an array with the initial heights. My quest continues and I will update the plunk once I am happy with what I've got.

Comment: @StuartHarding Please share the markup you'd like to use, and I'll gladly revise my answer to accommodate, to the best of my ability.

Comment: Head on over to [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/i2Fxol). All the stuff is on there with some more enhancements made since this reared its ugly CSS in IE not behaving mush.

Comment: I must just say though, it might only be on my machine that it isn't working correctly on. I have one Windows machine running Win10 and four Macs with various OSes, so if it works elsewhere, I'm happy to let it fail on my failure of a Windows laptop. The reason I say this is because the menus work in Parallels back to IE10 (obviously, IE9 will fail in animating the css), but that might be a fluke.

Comment: @StuartHarding This most recent plunk appears to work in Edge without any problems.

Comment: :-/ So, most likely a case of chasing my own tail then. I'm going to mark this as the correct answer as it did make me think about how the heights were used in a slightly different way from my own and might also be useful to others as well. Thanks, @Sampson.